# How to display only single validation error at a time

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I have this code to which displaying errors on my form

```
<input [ngFormControl]="form1.controls['thing']" type="text" id="thing" #thing="ngForm">
<div *ngIf='thing.dirty && !thing.valid'>
    <div class="err" *ngIf='thing.errors.required'>
        Thing is required.
    </div >
    <div class="err" *ngIf='thing.errors.invalid'>
        Thing is invalid.
    </div >
</div>
```

But in case of `thing` has two errors in it the two error show up.
Lets say if my input has `5 validators` so `5 divs` will show up which is not nice.
How to display just one `error div` at a time?

Answer (score 13):

You could create a custom pipe to get the first element of the errors object of the validator:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'first'
})
export class FirstKeyPipe {
  transform(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    if (keys && keys.length>0) {
      return keys[0];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This way you would be able to display only one error:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input [ngFormControl]="form.controls.input1">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls.input1.errors">
        <div *ngIf="(form.controls.input1.errors | first)==='required'">
          Required
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="(form.controls.input1.errors | first)==='custom'">
          Custom
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
  pipes: [ FirstKeyPipe ]
})
export class MyFormComponent {
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      input1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, customValidator])]
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/c0CqOGuzvFHHh5K4XNnA?p=preview.

**Note**: agreed with Günter to create a usable component ;-) See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Comment: You can combine this with [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) to clean it up a bit. Also, `firstKey` might be a more descriptive name for the pipe.

Answer (score 8):

If you have consistent markup for your error message blocks, then you can use css to display only the first message and hide the rest:

*css*

```
.message-block .error-message {
  // Hidden by default
  display: none;
}
.message-block .error-message:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

*markup*

```
<div class="message-block">
  <span class="error-message" *ngIf="myForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
    Email is required (first-child of message block is displayed)
  </span>
  <span class="error-message" *ngIf="myForm.get('email').hasError('email')">
    Invalid email format (error message hidden by default)
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the best solution, it allows choosing witch error is the more important to display.

Comment: While this works it means you have to hard code all the validation checks in the template.

Comment: Or `.message-block .error-message:not(:first-child) { display: none; }`. That way you don't have to override CSS.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input [ngFormControl]="form1.controls['thing']" type="text" id="thing" #thing="ngForm">
<div *ngIf='thing.dirty && !thing.valid'>
    <div class="err" *ngIf='thing.errors.required'>
        Thing is required.
    </div >
    <div class="err" *ngIf='!thing.errors.required && thing.errors.ivalid'>
        Thing is invalid.
    </div >
</div>
```

You could create a reusable component for showing errors so you don't need to repeat this code again and again.

Answer (score 2):

This works and you don't have to hardcode the validations in you template like @Joes answer above.

```
Template:
    <input id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password" [(ngModel)]="password"  [ngClass]="{'invalid-input': !formUserDetails.get('password').valid && formUserDetails.get('password').touched}">
          <div class="validation-container">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of userValidationMessages.password">
              <div class="invalid-message" *ngIf="formUserDetails.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && formUserDetails.get('password').touched">
                {{validation.message}}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>

CSS:
    .validation-container div {
      display: none;
    }

    .validation-container div:first-child {
      display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Angular2** behind the scene checks the status of the control and reacts accordingly. So if you don't want to have more validation at a time, you can logically play with **`AND(&&)`** or/and **`OR(||)`** or/and **`NOT(!)`** operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Custom Pipe` that checks first error equals with specified error:

**CUSTOM PIPE**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'equals'
})

export class Equals implements PipeTransform {

  transform(errors: any, error: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!errors)
      return false;

    const array = Object.keys(errors);
    if (array && array.length > 0)
      return errors[array[0]] === error;

    return false;
  }
}
```

You can have lots of error div but just one error will be shown:

```
// input is form.controls.input1
<div *ngIf="input.errors | equals:input.errors.required">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="input.errors | equals:input.errors.maxlength">MaxLength</div>
<div *ngIf="input.errors | equals:input.errors.pattern">Pattern</div>
```