# Email Validation with required overlaps in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, email, angular-reactive-forms

Using Angular Reactive Forms for validation of Email.

I added Validators Required and Validators Email but Its displaying both as shown in below image. I just want one Error to be displayed at a time.

[image]

HTML Code :

```
<form [formGroup]="NamFomNgs">

    <label>Email : 
        <input type="email" name="MylHtm" formControlName="MylNgs">
    </label><br>
        <div class="ErrMsgCls" *ngIf="(NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].touched || NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].dirty) && 
            !NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].valid">
            <span *ngIf="NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].errors.required">This field is required</span>
            <span *ngIf="NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].errors.email">Enter valid email</span>
        </div><br>

    <button [disabled]="!NamFomNgs.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Typescript Code :

```
NamFomNgs:FormGroup;

constructor(private NavPkjVaj: ActivatedRoute, private HtpCncMgrVaj: HttpClient,private FomNgsPkjVaj: FormBuilder)
{
    this.NamFomNgs = FomNgsPkjVaj.group(
        {
            MylNgs:[null,Validators.compose([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.email ])]
        });
}
```

I feel it's a bug in angular form.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36443142/7124761

Comment: weird, i dun get the error u get with exact same code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-email-val

Comment: How is that a bug? You have two errors, and you construct your html to display each error independently if its exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create common component to display validation message:

[custom-validation-with-error-message](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cutom-validation-with-common-message)

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">
    {{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

constrol-message.component.ts:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { CustomValidationService } from '../custom-validation.service'


export class ControlMessageComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  @Input() control: FormControl;

  constructor() { }

    /**
     * This method is use to return validation errors
     */
  get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return CustomValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(this.getName(this.control), propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
      if (this.control.valueChanges) {
        return CustomValidationService.showValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName])
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

    /**
     * This method used to find the control name
     * @param control - AbstractControl
     */
  private getName(control: AbstractControl): string | null {
    let group = <FormGroup>control.parent;

    if (!group) {
      return null;
    }
    let name: string;
    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach(key => {
      let childControl = group.get(key);
      if (childControl !== control) {
        return;
      }
      name = key;
    });
    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order to *display only the first* `<span>` in each `<div class="ErrMsgCls">...</div>` element and let me know if it helps:

#### HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="NamFomNgs">

    <label>Email : 
        <input type="email" name="MylHtm" formControlName="MylNgs">
    </label><br>
        <div class="ErrMsgCls" *ngIf="(NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].touched || NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].dirty) && 
            !NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].valid">
            <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].errors.required">This field is required</span>
            <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="NamFomNgs.controls['MylNgs'].errors.email">Enter valid email</span>
        </div><br>

    <button [disabled]="!NamFomNgs.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### SCSS

```
.ErrMsgCls {
    .invalid-feedback {
        display: none;
    
        &:first-of-type {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

#### If you use CSS

```
.ErrMsgCls .invalid-feedback {
     display: none;
 }

 .ErrMsgCls .invalid-feedback:first-of-type {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

or just

```
.ErrMsgCls > span {
     display: none;
}
 .ErrMsgCls > span:first-of-type {
     display: inline-block;
}
```